# Using `for` Loop inside React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create a table which changes dynamically. The number of its columns changes according to the number of days of the month (28, 29, 30, or 31).

I created the table manually (but the number of columns is fixed to 31):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAvPu.png

Here is the component in which I tried to select the number of columns manually according to the number of days of the current month (28,29,30,31), it shows nothing in the browser:

```
const Test = () => {
    // Number of days in the current month
    function daysInCurrentMonth() {
        var now = new Date();
        return new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();
    }

    let a = daysInCurrentMonth();
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {() => {
                            for(let i=1;i<=a;i++){
                                 <td>{i}</td>
                            }
                        }}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Test;
```

How can I use a *for* loop inside this code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to return the `td's` from the function you're writing in JSX and call the function as well like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {(() => {
            let td = [];
            for (let i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
              td.push(<td key={i}>{i}</td>);
            }
            return td;
          })()}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

A more efficient way to render it is to extract the function outside the JSX:

```
function daysInCurrentMonth() {
   var now = new Date();
   return new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
}

let a = daysInCurrentMonth();

const renderTD = () => {
  let td = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    td.push(<td key={i}>{i}</td>);
  }
  return td;
};

return (
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>{renderTD()}</tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

If you want to remove the `renderTD` function you can create a new array of length `a`, but I guess it's not a very efficient method to do this.

```
function daysInCurrentMonth() {
  var now = new Date();
  return new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
}
let a = daysInCurrentMonth();

return (
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {[...Array(a).fill(0)].map((_, i) => (
            <td key={i}>{i + 1}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code block inside your JSX does not result in any value.

Try replacing

```
 {() => {
    for(let i=1;i<=a;i++){
      <td>{i}</td>
    }
 }}
```

by something like:

```
Array(a).keys().map((i) => <td>{i-1}</td>)
```

There may be smarter ways than `Array(a).keys()` to generate the value range you need.

Comment: it show me an error ''TypeError: Array(...).keys(...).map is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Better you should use map().

Make sure you have your `i` as an array:

```
i.map(elem -=>  {
    return <td>elem</td>
})
```

Comment: but that will not works dynamically , i must initialize the i array like that  : const i = [1,2,3, ........... ,31];